# Python 2.7 How to redirect the "subprocess.Popen" results to files?

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, io-redirection

I am a tyro in Python and ran a brick wall on this. With the Python script attached, I was able to produce the desired console output for "Ping_Fail" and "Ping_Success" from multiple devices listed in the "ip.txt" file. How do I redirect the result to separate text files, "Ping_Fail.txt" and "Ping_Success.txt".

```
import subprocess
with open('ip.txt') as k: 
  devices = k.read().splitlines()
  for host in devices: 
        result=subprocess.Popen(['ping', '-c', '1', '-n', '-W', '2', host], 
            stdout=k, stderr=k).wait()
        if result:
          print host, 'Ping_Fail'
        else:
          print host, 'Ping_Success'
```